# Почему программа на C неправильно читает файл?

Tags: c, файлы

При компиляции программа не выдаёт ошибок, но во время запуска показывает неверные результаты:

[image]

Мне кажется, что она не читает зарплату работников, но я не знаю почему.

Сама задачка:

Дан файл содержащий сведения о  сотрудниках. Структура записи файла:
 - табельный номер.
 - Фамилия и инициалы сотрудника.
 - должность.
 - зарплата.

Написать программу, которая:
 1. выводит список сотрудников, по заданной должности;
 2. выводить список сотрудников с минимальной зарплатой;

Сам код:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<clocale>
#include<Windows.h>

struct SOTRUDNIK {
    char fio[21];
    char dol[21];
    int tn;
    int zarplata;
};

void Dol(int k, SOTRUDNIK * str);
void Zap(int k, SOTRUDNIK * str);

int main()
{
    int zap;
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    int i;
    FILE *f;
    struct SOTRUDNIK str[300];
    if ((f = fopen("сотрудники.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        puts("Файл не найден.");
    for (i = 0; !feof(f); i++) {
        fgets(str[i].fio, 20, f);
        fgets(str[i].dol, 20, f);
        fscanf(f, "%d %d", &str[i].tn, &str[i].zarplata);
    }
    int k = i;
    char c;
    bool proof = true;
    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 21; j++) {
            if (str[i].dol[j] == ' ')
                str[i].dol[j] = '\0';
        }
    }
    do {
        if (proof) {
            puts("___________________________________________");
            puts("Выберите действие:");
            puts("1-вывод сотрудников по заданной должности");
            puts("2-вывод сотрудников с минимальной зарплатой");
            puts("3-для выхода");
            puts("___________________________________________");
        }
        c = getchar();
        proof = true;
        switch (c) {
        case '1':
            Dol(k, str);
            break;
        case '2':
            Zap(k, str);
            break;
        case '3':
            return 0;
            fclose(f);
            break;
        default:
            proof = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    while (c = '!3');
}

void Dol(int k, SOTRUDNIK * str)
{
    char dolC[21];
    bool naiden = 0;
    puts("Введите должность:");
    scanf("%s", dolC);
    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++)
        if (strcmp(str[i].dol, dolC) == 0) {
            printf("%d %s %s", str[i].tn, str[i].fio,
                   str[i].zarplata);
            naiden = 1;
        }
    if (naiden == 0)
        printf
            ("В базе нет работника с такой должностью");
    puts("Для возврата в меню нажмите любую клавишу");
    getchar();
    getchar();
    system("cls");
}

void Zap(int k, SOTRUDNIK * str)
{
    int minzap = 100000;
    puts("Сотрудники с минимальной зарплатой:");
    puts("\n №  ФИО      зарплата");
    puts("___________________________________________");
    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
        if (minzap > str[i].zarplata)
            minzap = str[i].zarplata;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++)
        if (minzap == str[i].zarplata)
            printf("\n %d %s %d", str[i].tn, str[i].fio,
                   str[i].zarplata);
    puts("___________________________________________");
    puts("Для возврата в меню нажмите любую клавишу");
    getchar();
    getchar();
    system("cls");
}
```

Данные из текстового файла сотрудники.txt:

```
1 Васильев            секретарь                5000
2 Зубков              менеджер                 6000
3 Джексон             менеджер                 4000
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, несколько дней уже мешает эта проблема, сначала не хотел по мелочи беспокоить.

Comment: когда вставляешь код с неправильными отступами ты снижаешь шансы ответа втрое. Поправил как надо.

Comment: @Vladimir Gordeev, спасибо)

Comment: 1.Вы на каком языке пишете программу: на C или C++?

2. В каком порядке идут данные в файле сотрудники.txt? А в программе?
Если использовать сишные вызовы, то лучше считать по fgets всю строку до конца, а затем взять из неё данные sscanf. Если пишете на C++, то лучше использовать iostream.

3. Что такое `while(c='!3');`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) 67 строка:

```
while (c = '!3') -> while(c != '3');
```

2) В функциях Dol и Zap в циклах *`i<k`*

3) Из файла считываются данные не в том порядке. По идее надо:

```
fscanf(f, "%d %s %s %d", &str[i].tn, &str[i].fio,&str[i].dol,&str[i].zarplata);
```

4) 78 строчка: форматная строка неправильна. Надо: *`"%d %s %d\n"`*

5) В цикле ввода добавь

```
printf("%d %s %s %d\n",str[i].tn, str[i].fio,str[i].dol,str[i].zarplata);
```

и посмотри как вводятся данные. Вообще небезопасно использовать char-массивы и кириллицу. Могут быть проблемы с кодировками входного файла и консоли.

PS. Да и в целом код написан плоховато. В качестве имён переменных лучше использовать английские названия, а не транслит. Так же магические константы надо заменить на define:

```
#define MAX_STR_LEN 21
#define MAX_EMPLOYEES 100
```

PS2. Извините, не могу разобраться ещё с форматированием :)

Comment: Проблемы с кодировками вполне могут быть. Тут можно посоветовать после ввода массива вывести его на экран. Если будут крякозябры, то случай -- тот самый.

Comment: @ololo: мне кажется, лучше не давать правильный код, а лишь указывать, где неправильно и почему. Всё же задание учебное.

Comment: @VladD: да, наверно зря так сразу расписал. Но в принципе автор, несмотря на неряшливый стиль, написал почти работающую программу. Но некоторые моменты действительно позволяют думать, что он просто её скопировал откуда-то и не смог разобраться.

Comment: @ololo: мне тоже показалось, что ТС где-то взял готовую программу и лишь немного переделал её под своё задание. В любом случае, надеюсь, дискуссия поможет разобраться и понять, и доделать всё самостоятельно.

Comment: @ololo, благодаря вашим советам разобрался=) Самый полезный совет добавить в цикл ввода printf().